# Python thread loses access to filesystem

Tags: python, multithreading, alsa, file-access

I'm developing an embedded device that acts as a music player. It has a development board (orange pi zero 2), three joystick buttons and an rfid reader. The joystick buttons are connected via gpio and send events to /dev/input/event0.

Now, I have programmed the musicplayer using python. Since I need to monitor evdev events, react on button presses and handle music playback, the python program has three threads:

- One worker thread listens to key events from /dev/input/event0
- One worker thread handles music playback using pygame.mixer.music
- The main thread checks for button presses, decides what to do when a button was pressed or when an rfid card is detected.

Everything seems to work just fine at program startup. However, when I start playing songs from a playlist, after a while I get messages like this:

```
ALSA lib conf.c:4617:(snd_config_update_r) cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
```

Also, when the song ends and the next song has to be loaded, I get an Exception, that that file is not found, although, I'm absolutely sure that it is there:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4 (__do_play):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
  File "/opt/tobibox/tobibox/tobibox/musicplayer.py", line 218, in __do_play
pygame.error: No such file or directory: '/opt/tobibox/files/83f729cb-81fc-4038-b2af-65a16f68636e.ogg'.
```

So it seem like the python program lost permissions to access the file system. However, I have no idea what might be the cause of this. The program is running as root, because it needs access to /dev/input/event0, so it also has all necessary file permissions.

I have already tried to limit the "framerate" of all threads (I've added time.sleep(0.5) to each thread at critical locations). That seemed to relax the situation at least a little bit, since at least now the second song starts playing, but shortly after that I still get the same error messages.

Does anyone know what might cause this behavior or where I should start searching for errors?

I'm running python 3.10.4 on a
Linux xxx 5.19.4-sunxi64 #22.08.1 SMP Tue Aug 30 07:12:21 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

I don't know what else might be relevant, so if I should provide any other info about the system, please ask!

Comment: If you are sure that the file exists, then it looks like a permission issue. Rather than run the program as root, you can probably use a regular user and then add the user to the appropriate group in order to access `/dev/input/event0`. The group could be 'input' but I don't know what distro you use, the group could perhaps be something else. Probably it could help if you posted the Python code too.

Comment: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cannot-access-file-usr-share-alsa-alsa-conf-if-not-using-devmode-flag/15317

Comment: Thanks for your suggenstions. I've tried running as non-root user, but the problem still exists. I then tried to create a minimal example, but with a minimal example (one class in one file) I don't see the same problems. I'll try to analyze further, maybe strip down parts of the program one by one and hope to find the root cause...